# C# Windows Form Application : how to do something in background after the form has been loaded?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows Form Application, I successfully run the form:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

It works. I have the form loaded.

But if I do something in a cycle after the form has been loaded, say ...

```
String MyLog = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyLog.txt";

while (true)
{
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(MyLog, true))
                {
                    writer.Write("Hello");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

... the form is getting closed/crashed.

I tried to specify a special event handler in the Load property of the form but it didn't help:

This piece of code works (I have a string "Hello" written and the form is alive):

```
private void formLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          String MyLog = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyLog.txt";


                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(MyLog, true))
                    {
                        writer.Write("Hello");
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }
```

This piece of code doesn't work (I added a cycle) - the form is crashed:

```
   private void formLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          String MyLog = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyLog.txt";

          while (true)
          {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(MyLog, true))
                    {
                        writer.Write("Hello");
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
          }

    }
```

My question is how can I organize a code so that I can do something in the background after the form is loaded?

Comment: Where are you placing this code?

Comment: The form gets closed? Did it throw any error?

Comment: The form doesn't get "closed", it just never paints.  The UI thread is stuck in that while-loop it can't do anything else that UI threads need to do.  Like painting.  Use a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Richard, I'm placing a code to the event handler. Aiapatag, I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to do something like this you could use the `BackgroundWorker`. But there are some things you need to know. Firstly, to set it up, you need a `private` class variable and you need to put some code in the constructor:

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

::ctor
{
    _worker.DoWork += DoBackgroundWork;

    // we set this so you can cancel softly if necessary
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}
```

then you need to define the `DoWork` handler:

```
private void DoBackgroundWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    String MyLog = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyLog.txt";

    while (!_worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(MyLog, true))
        {
            writer.Write("Hello");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

and notice I'm checked the `CancellationPending` property to ensure we exit gracefully if necessary. Later on, if you need to (e.g. when you close the form), call this:

```
_worker.CancelAsync();
```

to shut it down.

Finally, to start it up, call this:

```
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Michael, thanks! Sorry, I didn't get the first piece of code. What does "::ctor" mean?

Comment: `::ctor` is the notation for the constructor. I don't know the name of your form so I couldn't put that there.

Comment: Michael, it seems to work: public Form1() {          InitializeComponent(); _worker.DoWork += DoWork;            _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; 
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); } What I worry about is with each "Hello" writing the memory consumed by the process is increased on 10-16 KB (I see it in Task Manager). Where could I miss something?

Comment: @Racoon, there must be more code in the do work handler than what was provided in the question then because the stream writer doesn't actually read the file into memory or anything and it's properly wrapped with a using.

Comment: Michael, first of all I marked your answer as accepted. Thanks for you help! As to my doWork handler, I don't have other code their. If I have just while (true) {Thread.Sleep(3000);}, no memory is consumed. But if I add "using" with writing to file, memory consumption gets huge.

Comment: @Racoon, consider getting rid of the entire `using` command and leveraging `File.AppendAllText` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `BackgroundWorker` component it was specifically designed to allow you to do work in the background and report progress/change to the UI.

Note that you're also pausing the UI thread by calling `Thread.Sleep(1000)` which probably won't end well.

You can find documentation on background workers here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx